# Enviar id con ajax a iframe modal

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un data tables con una serie de filas de que me dan un numero de radicado.. mas o  menos esta es la estructura

```
Id  nombre  radicado   acciones
1   daniel  HSVDFRG    [Botón del modal]
2   rosa    JNJNLKU    [Botón del modal]
3   mario   NJHHBG5    [Botón del modal]
```

Ahora, cuando doy click en el botón del modal, este abre un calendario y hasta ahi funciona bien, pero necesito que al ejecutar ese modal me lleve el valor del radicado a traves de ajax.

Lo estoy haciendo así:

El botón del modal, a través de la clase me ejecuta el JS y de paso lleva el dato del radicado.

```
<button data-id='.$row['rad'].' id='.$row['rad'].' title="Agendar" class="userinfo2 btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
```

Ahora, cuando ejecuta el JS, se abre bien el modal con el iframe, pero no me lleva el valor del data-id que es el número del radicado.

Mi js es:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.userinfo2').click(function(){
        var userid2 = $(this).data('id'); //Con este capturo el valor del radicado, si hago un alert hasta aquí viene bien el número 
        
$.ajax({ //Luego lo envió con un ajax así..
        url: 'actions/calendar/index.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {userid2: userid2},
        success: function(response){ 
         $('#modal2').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){      
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','actions/calendar/index.php')
        //Si el post es success debería mostrar la ventana del iframe pero a esta no llega la data que envié por ajax 
        })
           $('#modal2').modal({show:true})
        }
      });
        
    
        });
    });
```

cuando intento llamar la data enviada por ajax, con php me muestra que no llego nada..

```
$data = $_POST["userid2"];
echo '$data'; //Muestra que es Undefined index: userid2
```

Alguien me puede dar luces por favor?

Comment: Estas pasando el ID por el boton.. cuando deberias ponerlo en el modal, y exactamente en un input hidden dentro del formulario.

Comment: Hola @Jean Paul, los datos del tomo del botón para posteriormente enviarlos con ajax, no uso ningun formulario

Comment: Cuando el navegador carga un iframe, hace un GET, que sería una petición separada del POST con ajax. Lo que supongo que podrías haces es en el success cargar la respuesta de  `actions/calendar/index.php` en un elemento de la página.

Comment: Creo que intentas pasar un dato del boton, hacia un iframe?..

Comment: Así es @jean Paul, intentó en enviar un dato de la tabla a un iframe que carga en un modal y esto lo estoy intentando hacer con ajax

Comment: Entonces para eso debes utilizar window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false); para que tu iframe reciba los datos que envias del boton..

Comment: Gracias Jean Paul, logre llevar el valor del botón al iframe de una forma mas sencilla la cual dejo como respuesta por si a alguien le sirve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a Jean Paul y a Emeeus.

Yo se bien que mi petición era algo rara.. por demas..

La solución a mi problema es sencilla..

Recuerdan que captura el valor del boton asi...

```
 var userid2 = $(this).data('id');
```

Bueno como posteriormente debía llevar de alguna forma ese valor al iframe, pues se me encendio el foco y lo lleve a través de una variable así:

```
 $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','actions/calendar/index.php?rad='+userid2+'')
```

Luego cuando carga, el iframe ya me lleva el valor rad='+userid2+' y recupero ese valor con GET..

```
$myrad = (isset($_GET['rad']) ?$_GET['rad'] : NULL); 
echo $myrad; // Imprime por ejemplo NJHHBG5
```

Gracias por las ideas!